# Is hogan.js unmaintained? Is it safe to use?

Tags: twitter, mustache, templating, hogan.js

I've seen that Twitter's hogan.js is not making progress and it's somewhat abandoned (github: https://github.com/twitter/hogan.js). The issues are not being attended, and last version in NPM is 2.0.0 (https://www.npmjs.org/package/hogan.js), while in github is already 3.0.0. Eight months ago it was asked to be updated in NPM and it has not been done yet (https://github.com/twitter/hogan.js/issues/111).

Is Twitter still using Mustache templates? Why is this project so unattended? Would you use it for a real life product?

Comment: Looks to be receiving updates now.

Comment: Yes, recently mantainers said that they were launching 3.0.0 soon, but it seems that they still have some problems.

Comment: Still on v2.0.0 as of April 2014 on NPM while Github repo still says 3.0.0.

Comment: There is definitely activity now.

Comment: This looks like a valid question.